# Request_URI shows html entities instead ampersands - GET parameters not recognized

Tags: php, angularjs, fullcalendar

I'm running FullCalendar with AngularJS v1.2.9.
The uiConfig reads:

```
  $scope.uiConfig = {
calendar: {
  height: 400,
  width: 800,
  editable: false,
  events: 'calendardata.php',
  header: {
    left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'today prev,next'
  },
```

The call was failing - I looked at the REQUEST_URI hitting the MySQL server, and found
'/calendardata.php?start=1396162800&end=1399791600&_=1396894998356' - the ampersands had been converted to entities, so the GET variables are not recognized.

Both systems are using UTF-8. Has anyone seen/resolved this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that solved it for me was retrieving the values to a variable on the scope, and referencing the variable instead:

```
    $scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar: {
    height: 700,
    editable: false,
    events: $scope.eventSources,
    header: {
      left: 'month basicWeek basicDay',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'prev,today,next'
    },
```